# Losing one byte when storing data in SQL Server Image column

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, adodb

We have a legacy Classic ASP app that is using ADODB to store a document in an image column in SQL Server.  The problem we are running into is that a single byte is getting lost from most files.  We have one instance where a file won't lose a byte so I'm thinking it's potentially size related.

So far we have..

- Verified that the correct byte length is being passed to the adodb CreateParameter call.
- Used the SQL Server BCP tool to verify that the file is corrupt in SQL Server and not by our extraction.  When we extracted the file with BCP it is missing the byte AND we did use the -w parameter.

Does anyone have any advice on what we could try to do next?

UPDATE:

We have done some more research and it appears the byte is disappearing in adodb.  We do this..

> cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("SupportDocImage",adLongVarBinary,adParamInput,lSize,sFilePath)

Where lSize would be 123,139 and sFilePath is the binary data (yes.. bad naming)

This actually calls off to a stored procedure and in that stored procedure we will do a DATALENGTH(@Variable) and we instead get 123,138.

Also from what we have seen it is the last byte that gets lost.

Comment: Any particular byte? Is it the last one always?

Comment: It appears to always be the last byte but I will go verify with a pdf.

Comment: How does the SQL Statement look like? Try selecting the data length (`select data_length(col)`) just after inserting to make sure nothing comes later to modify the data.

Comment: Updated to mention we call off to a stored proc.  Checking the length in that stored proc shows the byte is missing.

Comment: We verified with a pdf that it is the last byte that gets lost (no clue how the pdf still loads properly)

Comment: Can you post more of your code and the definition of the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article.

The solution is for Oracle, but it is using ADO all the same.

http://forums.devshed.com/visual-basic-programming-52/inserting-blob-s-via-adodb-stream-using-a-stored-procedure-103030.html

Try adding +1 to the size.

Also, did you check this property off when uploading the image.

cmdSQL.Properties("SPPrmsLOB") = True

Regardless, you still have to write a stored procedure that takes a varbinary(max) or image data type and inserts it into the table.

Comment: We did try the +1 to the size and still had it break.  SPPrmsLOB is an Oracle provider specific setting based on that link + Google

Comment: Please post the whole vb script so that I can try.